# How I get rvm to work properly with gnome-terminal?

Tags: ruby, gnome-terminal, rvm

How do you get rvm to play properly with gnome-terminal?

```
wim@wim-desktop:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

wim@wim-desktop:~$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
wim@wim-desktop:~$ rvm use 1.9.3

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

I read [here](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/) that I just need to check "Run command as a login shell" in my gnome-terminal profile preferences, which I did and reopened a new terminal but it didn't work.  Then I read [here](https://rvm.io/support/faq/#shell_login) that to fix the configuration files automatically I can run:

```
wim@wim-desktop:~$ rvm get [head|stable] --auto
stable]: command not found
cat: /home/wim/.rvm/help/get: No such file or directory
Could not update RVM, get some help at #rvm IRC channel at freenode servers.
```

Which didn't work either, as you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it by putting in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```